# Can I pursue a PhD while working as an Accounting Instructor/Lecturer?

Tags: phd, career-path, professorship

I plan on becoming an Accounting Professor in the near future. What I was hoping to do was pursue my PhD while working for the university as a lecturer/instructor. I read that many people work as a lecturer while pursuing their PhD, and that many universities offer this opportunity. I also read that it usually depends on your field of study. That being said, my question is:

Is this the case for Accounting lecturers?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: United States of America

Comment: You may have got things backwards; yes, people work as TAs/ instructors during their PhDs, but they are there primarily as PhD students, not as lecturers (i.e. they apply for a PhD and use the TAship to pay for it, rather than being hired as a professor and then working on the PhD in their spare time). Check job ads for accounting professors and see what the required qualifications are-- that may well give you your answer.

Comment: That's not entirely true. For Tenure at most universities, you have to get the highest degree in your field, which in my case would be my PhD. Therefore, I could become a lecturer (like I said before, which is different from a professor), take my PhD part time. That's what many many people do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many fields—including accounting—which offer “adjunct” positions which allow professionals to give lectures while not having full PhD qualifications necessary to be a professor. They’re usually advertised as “adjunct” or “contract” positions. But it’s also true that in many disciplines, such instructor positions are given to graduate students. It’s largely a question of how financing in the given program is handled.